# Remove MS Word Formatting when pasted into RTE in JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, extjs, ms-word

i am using an EXTJS HTML Editor and the character is 2000, however i am stripping all the MS Word formatting that comes when you copy from word, i am using this function i found over here

```
function cleanHTML(input) {
    // 1. remove line breaks / Mso classes
    var stringStripper = /(\n|\r| class=(")?Mso[a-zA-Z]+(")? ^p)/g;
    var output = input.replace(stringStripper, ' ');

    // 2. strip Word generated HTML comments
    var commentSripper = new RegExp('<!--(.*?)-->','g');
    var output = output.replace(commentSripper, '');

    // 3. remove tags leave content if any
    var tagStripper = new RegExp('<(/)*(meta|link|span|\\?xml:|st1:|o:|font)(.*?)>','gi');
    output = output.replace(tagStripper, '');

    // 4. Remove everything in between and including tags '<style(.)style(.)>'
    var badTags = ['style', 'script','applet','embed','noframes','noscript'];

    for (var i=0; i< badTags.length; i++) {
        tagStripper = new RegExp('<'+badTags[i]+'.*?'+badTags[i]+'(.*?)>', 'gi');
        output = output.replace(tagStripper, '');
    }

    // 5. remove attributes ' style="..."'
    var badAttributes = ['style', 'start'];
    for (var i=0; i< badAttributes.length; i++) {
        var attributeStripper = new RegExp(' ' + badAttributes[i] + '="(.*?)"','gi');
        output = output.replace(attributeStripper, '');
    }
    return output;
}
```

However, i want to keep the font color intact, i have tried to remove the font parameter but it doesn't work.

Comment: Found over here where ? In this cases is good to have the reference.

Comment: @code4jhon "Found over here" by this i mean found here at "StackOverflow"

Comment: Yeah, but I meant that it would be nice to have a link to where you actually got that piece of code even if it refers to another SO question.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this issue this week and found this post, figured a solid response might help someone else out. Here are my findings after a days worth of work:

I have been trying to do the same thing, Alexander's answer does not fix the issue because the `<... style="color:"` is inside of a `<span>`tag (which gets removed in step 2).

And if the font isn't inside the span, all the way at the bottom of this function (step 5), all the style tags are being removed.

I have spent a full day working out a possible solution (with very little experience with RegEx) and I came up with this:

```
function CleanWordFormatting(input) {
    // 1. Remove line breaks / Mso classes
    var stringStripper = /(\n|\r| class=(")?Mso[a-zA-Z]+(")?)/g;
    var output = input.replace(stringStripper, ' ');

    // 2. Strip Word generated HTML comments
    var commentSripper = new RegExp('<!--(.*?)-->', 'g');
    var output = output.replace(commentSripper, '');
    var tagStripper = new RegExp('<(/)*(meta|link|\\?xml:|st1:|o:|font)(.*?)>', 'gi');

    // 3. Remove tags leave content if any
    output = output.replace(tagStripper, '');

    // 4. Remove everything in between and including tags '<style(.)style(.)>'
    var badTags = ['style', 'script', 'applet', 'embed', 'noframes', 'noscript'];
    for (var i = 0; i < badTags.length; i++) {
        tagStripper = new RegExp('<' + badTags[i] + '.*?' + badTags[i] + '(.*?)>', 'gi');
        output = output.replace(tagStripper, '');
    }

    // 5. Remove any unwanted styling
    // NOTE: Add your own list of 'blacklisted' css attributes here
    var badStyling = ['margin-top:', 'margin-bottom:', 'line-height:', 'mso-fareast-font-family:&quot;', 'font-weight:', 'margin:'];
    for (var i = 0; i < badStyling.length; i++) {
        attrStripper = new RegExp('(' + badStyling[i] + ')([^;]*)+[^]', 'gm');
        output = output.replace(attrStripper, '');
    }

    // 6. Remove any unwanted attributes
    var badAttributes = ['start'];
    for (var i = 0; i < badAttributes.length; i++) {
        var attributeStripper = new RegExp(' ' + badAttributes[i] + '="(.*?)"', 'gi');
        output = output.replace(attributeStripper, '');
    }

    return output;
}
```

These are the few lines to note that are different from the original:

```
var tagStripper = new RegExp('<(/)*(meta|link|\\?xml:|st1:|o:|font)(.*?)>', 'gi');
```

The above line has the |span| portion removed.

```
// 5. Remove any unwanted styling
// NOTE: Add your own list of 'blacklisted' css attributes here
var badStyling = ['margin-top:', 'margin-bottom:', 'line-height:', 'mso-fareast-font-family:&quot;', 'font-weight:', 'margin:'];
for (var i = 0; i < badStyling.length; i++) {
    attrStripper = new RegExp('(' + badStyling[i] + ')([^;]*)+[^]', 'gm');
    output = output.replace(attrStripper, '');
}
```

Next, I added this loop that will remove any unwanted styling tags

```
var badAttributes = ['start'];
```

Finally, remove style from the badAttributes variable.

This is kind of a hack job, but it's the only thing I've been able to get to work. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that

- the shown version works as intended,
- you have verified that the HTML contains `<font color=>`, not `<span style="color:">`,
- you only have a problem with the regexp

the following proposition holds: If you replace

```
new RegExp('<(/)*(meta|link|span|\\?xml:|st1:|o:|font)(.*?)>','gi');
```

with

```
new RegExp('<(/)*(meta|link|span|\\?xml:|st1:|o:)(.*?)>','gi');
```

the font tags won't be removed from the inserted HTML, and you will see the colors correctly.